# How do I get Javascript onto visual studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2019

My brother has been interested in learning Javascript and because Visual Studio has been a good program for me in C# I was wondering if it is possible to get Javascript onto Visual Studio. I have tried searching it up, but none of the results worked, is there a way? And if not, what are some good alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do so by integrating javascript extension. There are project templates for js libraries (angular or react) in vs2019 for web applications when you start a new project.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/javascript-in-vs-2019?view=vs-2019

But in all honesty, I think it is better to do js development in a ide like vs code, sublime or notepad++